# Передача данных между представлениями

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Необходимо передать введенные данные между представлениями. Записываю их в сессию и передаю в другое представление, но на выходе получаю только тип данных(Models.Order). Но при этом в БД данные записываются.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Order order)
    {
       Session["ord"] = order;
       return RedirectToAction("OrderConfirm");
    }

    public ActionResult OrderConfirm(Order order)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = Session["ord"];
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult OrderConfirm(Order order, string action)
    {

        var orders = Session["ord"];
        if (action == "Добавить")
        {               
            db.Entry(orders).State = EntityState.Added;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View();
    }
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <p>Подробности заказа: </p>
    @ViewBag.Message        
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="action" value="Добавить" />
    <input type="submit" name="action" value="Отмена" />
}
```

UPD.
Сделал при помощи сессий

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string name, int amount, decimal sum)
    {
            Order order = new Order();
            order.Name = name;
            order.Amount = amount;
            order.Sum = sum;
            Session["ord"] = order;
            return RedirectToAction("OrderConfirm");
    }

    public ActionResult OrderConfirm()
    {
        Order order = Session["ord"] as Order;
        if (order != null)
        {
            ViewBag.Name = order.Name;
            ViewBag.Amount = order.Amount;
            ViewBag.Sum = order.Sum;
        }
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult OrderConfirm(Order order, string action)
    {
        var orders = Session["ord"];
        if (action == "Добавить")
        {
            db.Entry(orders).State = EntityState.Added;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Вам требуется передать данные между представлениями в пределах обработки одного запроса или требуется передать данные между разными запросами?

Answer (score 1):

Зачем через сессию-то?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Order order)
{
   var myOrder = order;
   return RedirectToAction("OrderConfirm", new { order = myOrder});
}
```

Есть подозрения, что у вас выбирается `OrderConfirm(Order)`, а не `OrderConfirm(Order, string)`. Попробуйте пере

Попробуйте добавлять через `db.Set<Order>().Add(order)`

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Order order)
{
   var myorder = order;
   return RedirectToAction("OrderConfirm", new{ order = myorder, userAction = "Добавить" });
}

public ActionResult OrderConfirm(Order order)
{
    ViewBag.Message = order;
    return View();
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult OrderConfirm(Order order, string userAction)
{
    if (userAction == "Добавить")
    {               
        db.Set<Order>().Add(order);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View();
}
```

.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "MyCoolController", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <p>Подробности заказа: </p>
    @ViewBag.Message        
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="userAction" value="Добавить" />
    <input type="submit" name="userAction" value="Отмена" />
}
```

Comment: 1. В ViewBag.Message не записывается ничего 2. db.Set<Order>().Add(order); значение неопределенное

Comment: @Akmal Я не могу гарантировать, что мне на 100% понятен ваш замысел. Вы уверены (дебаггером), что управление передается в те экшны, которые вам нужны?

Comment: Я прохоил отладкой, и единственное что не понятно это, то что в строке var orders = Session["ord"]; он записывает мои введенные данные, а в строке ViewBag.Message = Session["ord"] только тип Models.Order и в представлении выводит его

Answer (score 1):

Передать данные между представлениями можно следующими способами:

- ViewBag
- ViewData
- Модель представления

Предположим есть контроллер с таким методом:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // SOME CODE HERE

    return View();
}
```

Чтобы передать в представление данные можно использовать один из вариантов:

```
ViewBag.MyProperty = 10; // Какое либо значение (строка, число или что угодно)
ViewData["MyProperty"] = 10; // Какое либо значение (строка, число или что угодно)
var model = new MyModel { MyProperty = 10 } // Создаем класс модели и эту модель в представление через return View(model)
```

В представлении считываете значение:

```
@ViewBag.MyProperty
@ViewData["MyProperty"]
@Model.MyProperty
```

Если у вас частичное представление (представление использует другое представление), то ViewBag и ViewData будут доступны в частичном представлении тоже. Модель (или ее часть) потребуется передать в частичное представление

```
@Html.Partial("MyPartialView", Model)
```

В главном представлении тоже можно заполнять значение ViewBag и ViewData и использовать их в частичных. Из частичного представления передать в главное таким образом не получится.

**Однако, я считаю, что Вы пытаетесь передать значения между различными запросами.** Такой вывод напрашивается из Вашего кода, поскольку Вы считываете 
"ord" в различных действиях (в Index вы его заполняете, а в остальных используете)

Для передачи значения между запросами можно использовать (хранятся на стороне сервера и не работают при отключенных cookies, кроме последнего):

- Кеш приложения ApplicationCache (если, например, Вам требуется отобразить одно и то же значение для разных пользователей)
- Сессию Session (если требуется сохранить данные между различными запросами одного и того же пользователя)
- TempData (то же самое, что и сессия, но автоматически очищается после следующего запроса, либо после первого использования в зависимости от версии asp.net)
- Cookies (добавление в ответ печенюшки с каким-то именем и значением, *хранится на стороне браузера пользователя*)

**Напишите в комментарии чем дополнить ответ, чтобы сделать его более точным, поскольку описать все перечисленные выше варианты с примерами коротко не получится.**

Comment: Получается мне надо передать между разными запросами. Буду благодарен если покажете пример с сессиями