# ASP.NET MVC - Передача данных во второе представление

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Мне необходимо по нажатию кнопки "Авторизоваться" передать значения из текстовых полей первого представления во второе представление и открыть его.

Что я должен написать в контроллере?

Представление 1

```
 <div class="form">

    <form class="register-form" method="post" action="~/Views/Library/Books">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Электронная почта" name="Email" />
        <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
        <p class="message">Передумали? <a href="#">Авторизация</a></p>
    </form>

    <form class="login-form" method="post">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Логин" name="Login" />
        <input type="password" placeholder="Пароль"  name="Password"/>
        <button>Авторизоваться</button>
        <p class="message">Забыли пароль? <a href="#">Вспомнить</a></p>
    </form>

</div>
```

Метод Auth

```
public ActionResult Auth()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Нужно создать еще один метод, который будет это выполнять? Не пойму, как это связать и как передать значения из представления

Comment: Вы пишете о двух представлениях, но в тексте код только одного, почему-то с двумя формами. Где вторая форма? У вас не сходится описание словами с написанным в коде. Что за задача? Сразу после регистрации на сайте залогинить пользователя в систему?

Comment: В контроллере нужно в параметрах метода указать передаваемые параметры.

Comment: Зачем вы добавили ненужный код формы регистрации?

Comment: [Передача данных между представлениями](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/556904/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8) - Дубликат?

Answer (score 0):

Передайте из первого представления значения необходимых текстовых полей на сервер. Там их получите и передайте в качестве модели во второе представление.